# Simple read-in file for a website

Tags: html, css, text

I want to make a simple one-page html page with css styling

(this is sort of a go-to help page on some subject.)  The content of the page will be really wordy, so I want to keep the content outside of the page.

I've used a simple read-in code like this

```
<?php

    $f = fopen("unitednations.txt", "r");

    // Read line by line until end of file
    while(!feof($f)) { 
        echo fgets($f) . "<br />";
    }

    fclose($f);

    ?>
```

This works wonders, as it allows everything in the style sheet to apply to whatever text is in the txt file that's fed through.  So it's effectively simply part of the page.

However I plan to host it somewhere simple, being a one page affair, I don't want to go through the trouble of finding a free host that offers php and all that jazz.

Like a css style sheet, I would like to "link in" a txt file and dump in on the page.

Html offers embed and object codes, but these don't allow for the CSS to do its thing, and I would like to even embed html code like links into the text file and have the page snap it up like normal.  It worked with php, I just want a similar alternative.

Thanks!

here's a doodle of what I planned to do

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

Here's a method using Javascript.

```
var contents = new XMLHttpRequest();
contents.open('GET', 'unitednations.txt');

contents.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=contents.responseText;
}
contents.send();
```

Replace PATH TO YOUR FILE with the path of the file you want to load. Also don't forget to replace content (5th line) with the id of the element you want to load the text into.

**Remarks**

That will only work if the user has Javascript enabled and you can only import files of your own domain. An easier way is to use the following:

**Frames**

```
<iframe src="unitednations.txt" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Don't forget to set the width and the height of the iFrame ;).

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery and replace the HTML of the body tag.

Not you'll have trouble testing these using Chrome and opening local files instead of opening files from a server (the server can be running locally though). Tested in IE.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('body').load('file_name.txt');
  });
</script>
```